# XMRig-Proxy Performance

Tags: mining, mining-pools, proof-of-work

I have a farm of around 50 rigs running xmrig.  I'm setting up xmrig-proxy, but am having trouble finding information.

Does it set individual difficulties?  I have some old desktops churning 200H/s up to gpu rigs turning 2KH/sec.  I noticed xmr-node-proxy does this, but wasn't sure of xmrig-proxy.

Also, on the comparison page for xmrig-proxy, it states Share Validation is "Basic" versus node-proxy being "Full".  What consists of "Basic" validation?  Will it still have a performance boost versus connecting all these a pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can define individual difficulty for miners connected to `xmrig-proxy`. However this only tells the miners which results to submit to the proxy. Another difficulty is set between the proxy and pool and this difficulty says which results (shares) will be submitted by the proxy to the pool.

So if your pool diff will be 100.000 and diff for miners (either by proxy config or individually as part of username) will be 10.000, proxy will receive all shares with diff >10.000, but will forward to the pool only those having diff >100.000.

At the end it doesn't matter if you submit diff X share every 10 seconds or diff X*2 share every 20 seconds.

Comment: So why even have the lower difficulties?  Wouldn't it be more efficient to even have the slower CPUs have the high difficulties to the proxy, so they toss the results locally instead of transmitting?

Comment: It is mainly useless :) But can be used to avoid network timeouts between miners and proxy.